# How can I suppress host key checking with ssh-agent

Tags: git, ssh-agent

I have a script with this snippet:

```
ssh-agent bash -c "ssh-add $SOME_KEY; \
                   git submodule update --init foo"
```

The script hangs while asking the user:

> RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:[the fingerprint]
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

How can I make the script continue (with a yes)?

---

- I know that I can invoke `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to disable this but I'm calling `git` not `ssh`.
- I know that I can configure `~/.ssh/config` to disable strict key checking for that host--but I don't want to modify the user's system.
- I know that I can `chmod 000 ~/.ssh/known_hosts` to disable key checking for that user, but I don't want to modify the user's system
- I thought I could insert `yes |`  in front of `git` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28527476?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Stack Overflow, via [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru), [passing ssh options to git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28527476/4957508):

> The recently released git 2.3 supports a new variable
>   "GIT_SSH_COMMAND" which can be used to define a command WITH
>   parameters.
>
> ```
> GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" git clone user@host
> ```
>
> > `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND` takes precedence over `$GIT_SSH`, and is
> >     interpreted by the shell, which allows additional arguments to be
> >     included.